# is it possible to update cell in bootstrap table in react?

Tags: reactjs, html-table

I have small project in order to learn react instead of razor pages and I am trying to create an editable table based on bootstrap table that is build from the state object

I am trying to implement edit possibility for the cells in a row that was selected for edits, but onchange event will update the state variable (different from what was used to draw the table) and as result the entire table instead of only one input and as a result input field is losing focus after typing 1 char. I put the keys whenever I can but it still updates and rerenders the whole table instead of the input of interest.

Maybe I need to supply each row () and each  with the keys also, because the keys that are passed to the HTML tags are not visible in react dev tools (see image [image])

I have a functional component that represents the entire page and I have render in it and to simplify investigation I am using this state variable

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
```

...

```
return (

    <Fragment>
        <Table striped bordered hover key={"Main-Table"}>
            <IncomesTableHeader key='header' name='header'></IncomesTableHeader>
            <tbody>
                <IncomesTableRowData key='table-body-main' name='table-body'></IncomesTableRowData>
            </tbody>
        </Table>
    </Fragment>
);
```

and also have some nested elements to the table

```
function IncomesTableHeader() {
    return (
        <thead >
            <tr>
                <the>...</th>
                <th>Income</th>
                <the>...</th>
                <the>...</th>
                <the>...</th>
                <the>.../th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    );
}

function IncomesTableRowData() {
    setRespdata(testincome);
    return (
        <Fragment>
            {Object.keys(respdata).map((keyName, keyIndex) =>
                <Fragment key={'fr-tr-gr-'+ keyName}>
                    <tr id={keyName} key={'tr-gr-'+ keyName} name={keyName}>
                        <td id={'G-'+keyName} colSpan="6">{keyName}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <TableGroupData key={'TableGroupData-' + keyName} id={'TableGroupData-' + keyName} name={'TableGroupData-' + keyName} Grouped={respdata[keyName]} >
                    </TableGroupData >
                </Fragment>
             )}
        </Fragment>    
    );
}

function TableGroupData({Grouped}) {
    var values = Grouped;
    return values.map(function (value) {
        if ( Object.keys(edits1).includes(value.ID)) {
            return (
                <RenderEditable key={'RetEdit-'+value.ID} Content={value} />
            )
        }
        else {
            return <RenderNotEditable key={'RetNotEdit-'+value.ID} Content={value} />
        }
    })
}
```

and here I have the editable row with inputs as a FormControl and as example I am trying to change the Income data

```
function RenderEditable({Content}) {
    var value = Content;
    return (
        <Fragment key={'f-Row' + value.ID}>
            <tr key={'Row' + value.ID} id={value.ID}>
                <td>...</td>
                <td key={'Income-' + value.ID}>
                    <div id={value.id}>
                        <FormControl key={'Income-' + value.ID} id={'Income-' + value.ID} name={'Income-' + value.ID} value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}></FormControl>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <<td>...</td>
                <td key={'btns-' + value.ID}>
                    <Button...>✓</Button>{' '}
                    <Button...>X</Button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

and not editable content

```
function RenderNotEditable({Content}) {
    var value = Content;
    return (
        <Fragment >
            <tr key={value.ID} id={value.ID}>
                <td>... </td>
                <td>
                    {value.Income}
                </td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>...</td>
                <td>
                    <Button>+/-</Button>{' '}
                    <Button>X</Button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

I will appreciate any help with it

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by moving everything to the render of the main function (functional component)
Also wrapped each table tag with the react components like

```
  ...
export function Row(props) {
return (
  <tr> 
    {props.children}
  </tr>
)}

export function Tdata(props) {
  var colspan;
  if (props.colSpan)
  {
      colspan=props.colSpan;
  }
  else {
      colspan=1;
  }
return (
  <td colSpan={colspan}> 
    {props.children}
  </td>
)}
...
```

end then used it like:

```
import * as MyTable from "components/Incomes/table"
export default function Incomes() {
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
...
render (
    ...
    <MyTable.Row id={keyName} key={'tr-gr-2-'+ keyName} name={keyName}>
        <MyTable.Tdata id={'G-'+keyName} key={'G-2-'+keyName} name={'G-2'+keyName} colSpan="6">{keyName}</MyTable.Tdata>
    </MyTable.Row>
    ...
)}
```